# How to add default telephone field in customer registration form in Magento 2.3.6

Tags: magento2.3, customer-account, register, field, account

I want to add default telephone field in our website Create and Account form.

I enable Telephone field under Store >> Configuration >> Customer >> Customer Configuration >> Name & Address Option >> Show Telephone (Required). But not show Telephone field in create customer account page.
How can i show for it?

http://devmag.visibleone.io/phom236/customer/account/create/

Comment: You have to create a custom module for that

Comment: just change to default theme (luma) and check if you can see it...

Answer (score 0):

First of all Create a simple module or if you are having custom module you can also use that

Create a file

Setup/Patch/Data/AddPhoneAttribute.php

Enter your own Vendor\ModuleName in namespace

```
<?php
namespace VendorName\ModuleName\Setup\Patch\Data;

use Magento\Catalog\Ui\DataProvider\Product\ProductCollectionFactory;
use Magento\Customer\Model\Customer;
use Magento\Eav\Model\Config;
use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\Patch\DataPatchInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\Patch\PatchRevertableInterface;
use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;

class AddPhoneAttribute implements DataPatchInterface, PatchRevertableInterface
{
   private $moduleDataSetup;
   
   private $eavSetupFactory;
  
   private $productCollectionFactory;
  
   private $logger;
   
   private $eavConfig;

   private $attributeResource;

   public function __construct(
       EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory,
       Config $eavConfig,
       LoggerInterface $logger,
       \Magento\Customer\Model\ResourceModel\Attribute $attributeResource,
       \Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface $moduleDataSetup
   ) {
       $this->eavSetupFactory = $eavSetupFactory;
       $this->eavConfig = $eavConfig;
       $this->logger = $logger;
       $this->attributeResource = $attributeResource;
       $this->moduleDataSetup = $moduleDataSetup;
   }

   public function apply()
   {
       $this->moduleDataSetup->getConnection()->startSetup();
       $this->addPhoneAttribute();
       $this->moduleDataSetup->getConnection()->endSetup();
   }

   public function addPhoneAttribute()
   {
       $eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create();


       $eavSetup->addAttribute(
           \Magento\Customer\Model\Customer::ENTITY,
           'phone_number',
           [
               'type' => 'varchar',
               'label' => 'Phone Number',
               'input' => 'text',
               'required' => 1,
               'visible' => 1,
               'user_defined' => 1,
               'sort_order' => 999,
               'position' => 999,
               'system' => 0
           ]
       );

       $attributeSetId = $eavSetup->getDefaultAttributeSetId(Customer::ENTITY);
       $attributeGroupId = $eavSetup->getDefaultAttributeGroupId(Customer::ENTITY);

       $attribute = $this->eavConfig->getAttribute(Customer::ENTITY, 'phone_number');
       $attribute->setData('attribute_set_id', $attributeSetId);
       $attribute->setData('attribute_group_id', $attributeGroupId);

       $attribute->setData('used_in_forms', [
           'adminhtml_customer',
       ]);

       $this->attributeResource->save($attribute);
   }

   public static function getDependencies()
   {
       return [];
   }

   public function revert()
   {
   }
       public function getAliases()
   {
       return [];
   }
}
```

Create another file
view/frontend/layout/customer_account_create.xml
Change `Vendorname_Modulename` with your own Vendor_Module

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     layout="1column"
     xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
   <body>
       <referenceContainer name="form.additional.info">
           <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template"
                  name="phone_number"
                  template="Vendorname_Modulename::extra_field.phtml"/>
       </referenceContainer>
   </body>
</page>
```

Create another file
view/frontend/templates/extra_field.phtml

```
<div class="field phone_number required">
   <label class="label" for="phone_number">
       <span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Phone number')) ?></span>
   </label>
   <div class="control">
       <input type="text" name="phone_number" id="phone_number" value="" title="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr(__('Phone number')) ?>" class="input-text" data-validate="{required:true}">
   </div>
</div>
```

Now run and field will added to your registration form

> php bin/magento setup:upgrade && php bin/magento setup:di:compile
> && php bin/magento s:s:d -f && php bin/magento cache:flush